# how to add a dynamic image src with laravels blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My question is very simple. i use blade in laravel to show the images like

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/image.jpg')}}">
```

but what if my image is dynamic like:

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/$imgsrc')}}">
```

i cant use

```
 <img src="{{asset('assets/images/{{ $imgsrc')}}">
```

because then i will end with:

```
 <img src="http://localhost/assets/images/{{ $imgsrc">
```

How can i call to a $variable in a blade {{}} call?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/').'/'.$imgsrc}}">
```

**EDIT**

when you need printing more than one strings where there may be variables,functions... you need to concatenate them

Also `asset('assets/images/')` is equivalent to `asset('assets/images')` so you need to add `/` before printing your variable `$imgsrc`

Finally, in Blade `{{"foo"}}` is equivalent to `<?php echo "foo" ?>`

Comment: it removes the last slash assets/images/ becomes assets/imagestherighsrc.jpg (notice assets/images(/) is missing

Answer (score 8):

> How can i call to a $variable in a blade {{}} call?

The normal PHP way. A blade `{{}}` is just the equilivant of `<?php echo() ?>`

So the answer to your question is:

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/images/' . $imgsrc) }}">
```

Comment: Your Answer is correct but {{}} is not equivalent of <?php ?>

Answer (score 1):

Mine had multiple dynamic parts in the src and this is how I did it after getting in the right direction, thanks to @Laurence's answer.

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$parentFolderName.'/'. $clientNameFolder .'/logo/').'/'.$event[0]->event_logo}}" class="event-page-country-logo">
```