# How to set dynamic textbox name in blade template?

Tags: php, laravel-blade

How can I add dynamic textbox name in blade template, I tried this but it didn't work -

```
{!! Form::text('update_arr[$i]["id"]', $key['zip'] ,array('class' => 'form-control','id' =>'zip','placeholder' => 'zip')) !!}
```

I want to loop through `$i` in text box name? like in simple html we can do -

```
<input type="text" name="update_arr[<?php echo $i;?>]['id']" />
```

any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712910/how-to-add-a-dynamic-image-src-with-laravels-blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care about your quotes,

```
{!! Form::text("update_arr[$i]['id']", $key['zip'] ,array('class' => 'form-control','id' =>'zip','placeholder' => 'zip')) !!}
              ^^              ^^  ^ ^//just replaced the single quotes with double one and vice versa
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, I solved it by this reference - [how to add a dynamic image src with laravels blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712910/how-to-add-a-dynamic-image-src-with-laravels-blade) 
May be it will help to others

```
{!! Form::text('update_arr['.$i.']["id"]', $key['zip'] ,array('class' => 'form-control','id' =>'zip','placeholder' => 'zip')) !!}
```

Thanks much!